# Pass a JSON value from curl response to a new file

Tags: bash

I ran curl request that gets a JSON response:

```
[{"id":"19","org_name":"test","uuid":"5b9f938d0bdeac1b41bc"},"EventTag":[]}]
```

I'm trying to get the "id" number, **only** from the first line and then to create a new json file on the disk when I place the "id" number in the right place. (as you can see, I pass the id 19 from the first line to the new Json file.

```
{"request": {"Event": {"id": "19", "task": "new"}}}
```

any idea?

Comment: Are the lines from `curl` supposed to end with `}` instead of `:`?

Comment: Question edited.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming input of

```
[{"id":"19","org_name":"test","uuid":"5b9f938d0bdeac1b41bc"},"EventTag":[]}]
```

you can use

```
curl ... | jq '.[0].id | {request: {Event: {id: ., task: "new"}}}' > output.json
```

- The `-s` wraps the input into a single array.
- `.[0].id` extracts the ID from the first element ...
- ... which is used as the value of the `id` key in the inner object.

Comment: I got an error:  jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "id"  

I edited the Question with the original curl response.

Comment: Since your response is already an array, you don't need the `-s` option.